# Troubles with dynamic and immutable arrays of control

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

In WPF C#, in code behind, I have to dynamically create an Array of Canvas (each Canvas also Children controls like Label, TextBox, Button etc.)

```
Canvas[] cv = new Canvas[myInt]; 
Label[] l = new Label[myInt];
TextBox[] tb = new TextBox[myInt];
...
Canvas.Children.Add(...);
```

Each of the Canvas can be dynamically added or removed. The issue is I have to give the Canvas array a length, and if one of the Canvas is removed the index will still remain and the afterwards elements cannot be pushed upward.  If later on I add new Canvases, the new Canvas may have a possibility to go out of range, unless I instantiate a very large Array from the beginning.

Is there a better solution to that? Would ArrayList, or List or what else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems obvious but since you do not know in advance how many elements you have to store you should use a `List<Canvas>`, `List<Label>` etc. then you can use the methods `list.Add()` and `list.Remove()`.

Don't use ArrayList, you want your data strongly typed and be able to add and remove items dynamically - so [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) would fit the bill.